# How to redirect https to http without using ssl certificate on localhost

Tags: ssl

i have my own http/s server and installed microsoft layered service provider(i can modify data, that browser send) on localhost.

So my question is. How teoreticaly can i redirect, the browser using port 443(https) to port 80(http) without need of ssl handshake. I need to get the data unencrypted, thats the reason. I really dont want to buy/use/generete ssl certificate! I only need it on localhost, so no dirty work :)

Answer (score 2):

While there are ways to do this without a certificate (DH-ANON cipher suites), basically no web browser supports DH-ANON, so it won't work.  The easier way is to just create your own self-signed certificate (at least you don't have to buy it).  [This](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html) tells you how to do that.

Comment: i know how to do that, but the certificate will not be thrsted and thats the point, the browser cant yell warning

Comment: Are there users other than just you?  If not, add your CA to the browser trust store.

Comment: i have multiple domains, thrust me :), its not possible for me to have valid ssl cert, becouse i have to know the domain before establishing ssl handshake. And thats the problem(generating ca on runtime with signing with ca imported to cert store). Becouse i dont know that fckin domain name! :). If rDNS worked correctly....

Comment: Server Name Indication was created exactly for that reason ( https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Server_Name_Indication ).  Or you could use a wildcard certificate.